# SQL injection prevention with 'AS QUERY'

Tags: c#, sql-injection

I have the following code which seems pretty standard on face value, however in query is another SQL statement hence why the 'AS QUERY' is at the end of the SQL string. I wanted to know if there was a sophisticated approach to parameterising the following SQL command instead of concatenating the entire query together.

The only solution I could think of would be to instead of having a query as a string, have it as an `SQLCommand` type object and initiate 2 commands. 1 to could and the other to display the preview of the data.

```
public static CommandStatus<int> GetQueryRecordCount(SqlConnection connection, String query)
{
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (" + query + ") AS QUERY";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = GetTimeout();

    try
    {
        SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dataReader.Read();

        String count = dataReader[0].ToString();
        dataReader.Close();

        return new CommandStatus<int>(Int32.Parse(count));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new CommandStatus<int>("Failed to GetQueryRecordCount[" + sql + "]:" + e.Message, e);
    }
}
```

String SQL will end up being something like this

```
"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT TOP 20 [RecordID],[Name],[SonsName],[DadsName],[MothersName],[DaughtersName] FROM [dbo].[sample] ) AS QUERY"
```

Comment: There are no values in that string so there are no parameters except perhaps the number of rows returned by `TOP`. `AS QUERY` isn't a keyword, it's just an alias for the subquery. What's the point of this code anyway? It will return either 20 or the number of samples if there are fewer than 20.

Comment: Where does the "query" parameter come from ? If it is one of available values within the same module then the risk of sql injection is vanishigly small. If it comes from some user input, on the other hand, it is a bona fida sql injection risk.

Comment: You maybe could use SqlParameter. This is often used to pass parameters in a 'secure' way

Comment: @DanielSchmid Table and column names cannot be supplied as SQL parameters.

Comment: @Amy: well, they *can*, as long as you then build the resulting query dynamically. (I mention this not to be pedantic but because passing them as parameters to a stored procedure that then checks against a whitelist is a legitimate way of doing business, as opposed to having to build the whole thing dynamically and opening the door to completely arbitrary queries.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, the parameters could be used to generate a line of dynamic SQL which is then executed using `sp_executesql`

Comment: I would suggest: using `COUNT(*)` (COUNT_BIG is even better but then you need a `long` as result) and using `ExecuteScalar` with a cast to `int` instead of using a resultset and converting the count to and from a string. Other than that, it all comes down to how trusted the incoming query is (but the lack of any way to pass parameters suggests that its quality is suspect).

Answer (score 0):

This function is literally SQL injection by design.

**Whitelisting** the SQL queries this function will accept is the only way to make it safe.

That is, the caller won't be able to inject *any* SQL query, they'll only be able to pick from a fixed list of pre-vetted queries. The list could even be defined as an array of static strings in the function you show.

But then they don't need to pass the whole query as a string, they only need to pass an ordinal integer to identify which query in the whitelist to run.